# Inbound and Outbound Rules Confusion Azure

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network, azure-nsg

I am using same NSG for two subnets in a VM. Now i have created a Custom rule where VM1 cannot accept packets from VM2. But default NSG rule allows VM2 to send packets to VM1.

Here are the pictures - [Vm2 to Vm1 outbound default rule created by NSG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NMg5O.png)

[Vm1 custom inbound rule set by me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4CFXf.png)

Does VM2 communicate with VM1 or can VM1 receive packets from VM2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your screenshot displayed, VM2 can send packages to VM1 but VM1 can not receive packages from VM2 because the inbound traffic from VM2 is blocked.

For a short test. VM1 is VMb and VM2 is VMc in my example.

The NSG setting of both subnets

[image]

From VMb to VMC
[image]

From VMC to VMb

[image]